# What causes duplicated() to behave differently?

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a problem where duplicated behaves differently in 2 nearly identical lines of code. The df looks something like this:

```
odonata = data.frame(H = c(2019071600, 2019071600, 2019071600, 2019071601, 2019071602), name = c(null, odonata, null, null, odonata)

#      H         name
# 2019071600     null
# 2019071600     odonata
# 2019071600     null
# 2019071601     null
# 2019071602     odonata
```

When I use this line:

```
odonata = odonata[which(!duplicated(odonata$copydate)),]
```

The output is like this:

```
#      H         name
# 2019071600     null    
# 2019071600     null
# 2019071601     null
```

But when I use the same code on this df:

```
araneae = data.frame(H = c(2019071600, 2019071600, 2019071600, 2019071601, 2019071602), name = c(null, araneae, null, null, araneae)

#      H         name
# 2019071600     null
# 2019071600     araneae
# 2019071600     null
# 2019071601     null
# 2019071602     araneae

araneae= araneae[which(!duplicated(araneae$copydate)),]
```

The output is like this:

```
#      H         name
# 2019071600     araneae
# 2019071601     null
# 2019071602     araneae
```

Now, I would like it to be like the output of araneae (for more than these two examples). The odonata df and the ones that come after it (alphabetically), seem to have this issue. I figured the problem was that it picked the top most duplicate as the result after automatically sorting it alphabetically. I have tried:

- Grouping by H
- Making 'name' numeric values (0 & 1)
- Using sort() or dinstinct()
- Variants of "odonata = odonata[which(!duplicated(odonata$copydate)),]"
- Maybe more I can't remember

But everything I tried made it worse. The closest I got was having only duplicate H when there was name = "null" AND name = "odonata", but I distinctly don't want duplicate H and I want it to pick odonata from the duplicate H for every H that has an odonata.

I hope the info suffices, TIA!

Comment: Could you add a table with your desired result?

Comment: Do you mean `araneae[which(!duplicated(araneae$copydate)),]`?

Comment: @Roland ah yes, sorry. Should be correct now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite get logic of what you want to include, but duplicated works like this:

```
X = c("a","a","b")
duplicated(X)

[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Anything that comes in the second time is considered duplicated. So when you do it on your data.frame, it is only dependent on `copydate`

If there is a certain preference to the second column, you would sort the data.frame first:

```
araneae = data.frame(H = c(2019071600, 2019071600, 2019071600, 2019071601, 2019071602), name = c("null", "araneae","null","null","araneae"))

araneae = araneae[order(araneae$H,araneae$name),]

araneae[!duplicated(araneae$H),]
           H    name
2 2019071600 araneae
4 2019071601    null
5 2019071602 araneae
```

If you like null to be choosen, before araneae, you do:

```
araneae$name = factor(araneae$name,levels=c("null","araneae"))
araneae = araneae[order(araneae$H,araneae$name),]
araneae[!duplicated(araneae$H),]

           H    name
1 2019071600    null
4 2019071601    null
5 2019071602 araneae
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, the problem was that odonata did not show up after deduping. Your solution for choosing which string to choose first did the trick! thank you so much!